# Unity Coroutine Freeze on iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, coroutine

i've been trying to make an app for mobile (both iOS and Android) and what this app does is quite simple:

1. Download a txt file from webserver
2. "Run" txt, the txt file has a command like "display" or "play" with an URL to resource (jpg or mp4)
3. Download or stream the resource to a texture in the scene (done)
4. Using GoogleVR (LatestVersion) to shot the whole thing

Now the problem is that as i start the coroutine to download stuff the game freezes on mobile but it doesn't freeze while in Editor.

Here's the code:

```
IEnumerator retrieveCommand(){
    print ("Retrieving command...");
    WWW rx = new WWW (host + "command.txt"); // host is the URL of server
    yield return rx; // wait for end WWW
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (rx.error)) { // if there's an error i stop execution of coroutine
        print (rx.error);
        mex.text = rx.error;
        yield break;
    }
    print ("Command: " + rx.text);
    if (lastCommand != rx.text.Trim ()) { // if last command retrieved is NOT the same as the current
        lastCommand = rx.text.Trim ();
        command = rx.text.Trim ();
        string[] argv = command.Split ('|'); // command is in form of <cmd>|parameter
        mexdisplay = argv [0]; // argv[0] contains command, argv[1] contains the paramter
        switch (argv [0]) { // what's the command?
        case "PLAY":
            video.GetComponent<MediaPlayerCtrl> ().Play ();
            break;
        case "STOP":
            video.GetComponent<MediaPlayerCtrl> ().Stop ();
            break;
        case "PAUSE":
            video.GetComponent<MediaPlayerCtrl> ().Pause ();
            break;
        case "GRAB": // set video resource
            try {
                video.GetComponent<MediaPlayerCtrl> ().m_strFileName = host + argv [1];
            } catch (Exception e) {
                print ("Exception: " + e);
            }
            break;
        case "DISPLAY": // downloads and shows picture
            print ("Display: " + host + argv [1]);
            rx = new WWW (host + argv [1]);
            yield return rx;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (rx.error)) {
                print (rx.error);
                mex.text = rx.error;
                yield break;
            }
            video.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.mainTexture = rx.texture;
            break;
        }
    }
    asdf = true;
}
```

The coroutine is called every 10s by Update:

```
void Update(){
    if(asdf){ // bool, if false -> running coroutine, if true -> not running->count 10 seconds
        curr += Time.deltaTime;
        if (curr >= time) { // time=10f, if counted to 10s start coroutine and reset timer
            asdf = false;
            curr = 0;
            StartCoroutine (retrieveCommand ());
        }
    }
}
```

edit:
So it turns out it's like the camera stops rendering... any help? i'm using the GoogleVR camera prefabs...

Comment: Does your AndroidManifest contain the needed permissions for accessing the internet?

Comment: Yes it does, it can connect to internet, there's no problem with that